# Simple nested for loops erroring out with 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I am currently writing a simple macro to determine who is scheduled during what time slot and record that time slot on another sheet. Everything works just fine until until the name of the person who is on the last time slot is compared to the last time slot. At this point the for loop "j" goes to -1 and causes the macro to error out.

I have included my entire code below but this is the line that the debugger points to is
watchStation = ActiveSheet.Cells(j, k).Value

```
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet, masterSheet As Worksheet, myBook As Workbook 'Define your workbooks and worksheets as variables

    Option Compare Text 'Makes string comparisons case IN-sensitive

    Sub Watch_Bill()

    Set myBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    Set masterSheet = Sheets("Musters")
    MsgBox masterSheet.Name

    Dim memberName, memberFirstWatch, memberSecondWatch As String
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim watchStation, watch As String

    lastRow = masterSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    'lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

    'Cycle through each member of the duty section
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        memberName = masterSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value

        'Cycle through watch bill to find member's watches
        For j = 9 To 18     'Row 9 starts the section of the watchbill that contains watches
            'MsgBox j
            For k = 2 To 9 'Column 2 through 9 contain watches
                watchStation = ActiveSheet.Cells(j, k).Value

                'MsgBox watchStation
                If InStr(watchStation, memberName) <> 0 Then

                    'Determine what watch station member is on
                    If j = 9 Or j = 10 Then
                        watch = "0700-1200"
                    ElseIf j = 11 Or j = 12 Then
                        watch = "1200-1700"
                    ElseIf j = 13 Or j = 14 Then
                        watch = "1700-2200"
                    ElseIf j = 15 Or j = 16 Then
                        watch = "2200-0200"
                    Else: j = 17 Or j = 18
                        watch = "0200-0700"
                    End If
                    'MsgBox "Found member"

                    'Check if member already had watch
                    If memberFirstWatch = "" Then
                        'MsgBox "member's first watch"
                        memberFirstWatch = watch
                    Else
                        'MsgBox "member's second watch"
                        memberSecondWatch = watch
                    End If

                    'Fill in member's watch times on muster sheet
                    masterSheet.Cells(i, 11).Value = memberFirstWatch
                    masterSheet.Cells(i, 12).Value = memberSecondWatch
                End If
            Next k
        Next j

        memberFirstWatch = ""
        memberSecondWatch = ""

    Next i

    End Sub
```

Thanks for any help anyone can provide. This is driving me nuts and I havent been able to figure it out for hours now.

Comment: I think you need to change the Else at the end to another ElseIf. As it is now you're setting j to True (17 OR j =18).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doug is right. I'll try to explain what's happening. Anybody feel free to correct me.

As Doug pointed out, the problem is the line

```
j = 17 Or j = 18
```

Since there is no `If`, VBA tries to evaluate it as an assignment of `j`

```
j = (17 Or j = 18)
```

Now what is `17 Or j = 18`? The right side `j = 18` is `True` because `j` is 18 at that moment. So we have

```
j = (17 Or True)
```

Now we could say that `anything Or True` is always true but we can go a little deeper. How do you use an `Or` with numbers? You use the bitwise comparison of the binary numbers, e.g.

```
   00001011 
Or 00010010
-----------
 = 00011011
```

We do the same when dealing with numbers and booleans. `False` is stored as all 0s and `True` is stored as all 1s which yields the exact behavior we want with `Not`, `And`, `Or`, `XOr`. E.g. `anything Or True` becomes:

```
   xxxxxxxx
Or 11111111
-----------
 = 11111111
```

Of course using only 1 bit would also show the same behavior but we don't have 1 bit data Types. So `17 Or j = 18` is `True` which is stored as `11...11` which is `-1` when read as an integer.

Note that I ignored different byte sizes of the data types.

VBA does a lot of implicit conversion for you which can be nice, especially for numbers <-> strings but it can lead to problems that only become apparent later in the code. 
For example accidentally storing a number as a string and then adding it to an actual number will work (the string will be converted). Adding two numeric strings however will concatenate them.

Comment: This is why I love you guys. Not only do you provide the right answer very quickly, but you also take the time to explain why it is what it is. Super simple fix that I would have never though to go to. Thank you again!